# JavaScript Chrome Console - Date offset command returns UTC-8 even when Chrome Sensor Location is initialized to Baltimore, Maryland (UTC-5)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, date, timezone, offset

Provided I have done everything correct, I receive an incorrect offset of -8, when initializing my Chrome dev tool to a location of Baltimore, MD, Latitude 39.3904, Longitude -76.6122 (US/Eastern TimeZone ID) Locale - en_US.

How do I make the my configuration work produce the offset of -5 using these two commands?

```
offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();  //positive minutes
offset/=-60;  //negative hours
```

[image: Screenshot of Sensor Location and Date Offset Commands]

Comment: Longitude would be negative: `-76.6122`

Comment: Thank you for the clarification and correction, I will change now, per my misunderstanding of coordinate representation

Comment: Why do you believe setting devtools location would affect the system local time zone?

Comment: Thank you for the hint,  I have subsequently went back to the codebase and pulled offset from user time and its difference from system time to get delta offset for computing time from timezone.

Comment: When it comes to time zones, things are never quite as simple as you might think.  The approach you describe will work for a single consistent timestamp (such as "now"), but one can't assume the offset is the same for other timestamps.  Please read the section *"Time Zone != Offset"* in [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).  And also you might enjoy watching [*The Problem with Time & Timezones*](https://youtu.be/-5wpm-gesOY) on YouTube.

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint, to the point of being workable for a consistent timestamp, would this be also the case for a system that is always in one location, whose user time offset if computed on the client and sent to the server from that one location system time (in my case PST - America/Los_Angeles)?

Comment: Please note, my neglecting to consider Day Light Savings time, because I have not done such an adjustment before.

Comment: Yes.  A single location can and often does have more than one offset, depending on which date and time is applicable.   Changes occur regularly in time zones around the world, both for DST reasons and for changes in standard time offset.  If you are talking about more than one exact point in time, don't send a client's offset to the server.  Send the client's time zone *identifier* instead.  In JS you can get that with `Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone`

Comment: That will likely be revised on next code review, but I am vaguely understanding as to why you say to use time zone identifier (America/Los_Angeles, in our case).  Do I understand the reason correctly that it to be done per suggestion because the location of the system could change to some other location or region outside of Los Angeles and change our offset?  What is the benefit of sending the time zone identifier instead, of offset, as per the suggestion?  What would happen if the offset method of sending to server does not change?